# Union issue in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, union

I have two dataframe"- dm_turnover_tmp_vend_all(columns:-'dmmcu', 'dmitm', 'dmvend', 'ibvend') and we79pvwf(columns:-'dmmcu', 'dmitm', 'dmvend', 'ibvend'). I need to append we79pvwf in 1st dataframe.
SO I tried this:-

```
dm_turnover_tmp_vend_all=dm_turnover_tmp_vend.union(we79pvwf)
```

I got error :-

```
AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns, but the first table has 3 columns and the second table has 4 columns;
'Union false, false
```

When I check column,

```
dm_turnover_tmp_vend_all.columns
```

Output:- `['dmmcu', 'dmitm', 'dmvend', 'ibvend']`

```
we79pvwf.columns
```

Output:- `['dmmcu', 'dmitm', 'dmvend', 'ibvend']`

How is this possible? Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Check if your `dm_turnover_tmp_vend` dataframe ghas same number of columns or not..

Comment: @notNull I did and i found same column name. I have updated above question too. Please have a look at it.

Comment: you are using `dm_turnover_tmp_vend` dataframe in your union not `dm_turnover_tmp_vend_all` this one.. can you check the column names in `dm_turnover_tmp_vend` in this dataframe?

Comment: try with unionByName as mentioned in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Seems one of your `dataframe` is missing `one` column, if your not sure about column order or missing some columns then,

Try with [`unionByName`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName) if you are missing some columns.

**`Exmaple:`**

```
dm_turnover_tmp_vend = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], ["dmmcu", "dmitm", "dmvend"])
we79pvwf = spark.createDataFrame([[4, 5, 6, 7]], ["dmmcu", "dmitm", "dmvend", "ibvend"])

dm_turnover_tmp_vend_all=dm_turnover_tmp_vend..unionByName(we79pvwf,allowMissingColumns=True)

dm_turnover_tmp_vend_all.show()
#+-----+-----+------+------+
#|dmmcu|dmitm|dmvend|ibvend|
#+-----+-----+------+------+
#|    1|    2|     3|  null|
#|    4|    5|     6|     7|
#+-----+-----+------+------+
```